# MVC3 - Unobtrusive validation multiple controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I've created a jQuery function for unobtrusive MVC 3 validation...

```
$.validator.addMethod('dtdt',
    function (value, element, parameters) {

        var idmonth = '#' + parameters['m'];
        var idyear = '#' + parameters['y'];
        var idhour = '#' + parameters['h'];
        var idminute = '#' + parameters['mn'];
        var controlmonth = $(idmonth);
        var controlyear = $(idyear);
        var controlhour = $(idhour);
        var controlminute = $(idminute);
        var mv = controlmonth.val();
        var yv = controlyear.val();
        var hv = controlhour.val();
        var mnv = controlminute.val();

        if (value == "" || mv == "" || yv == "" || hv == "" || mnv == "") 
            if (value != "" || mv != "" || yv != "" || hv != "" || mnv != "")
                return $.validator.methods.required.call(
                    this, value, element, parameters);

        return true;
    }
);
```

The idea behind this is that I have 5 dropdown controls next to each other (Day, Month, Year, Hour and Minute).  I've put this validator on the Day dropdown.

The rule is:- If one is empty then they must all be empty.  I one if filled in, then they must all be filled in.

The Day dropdown value is passed into the function using "value".  The other values are retrieved directly from the controls.  This bit is working fine.

When I debug, the code correctly seems to call the "return $.validator" statement exactly when I expect it.  However the form still seems to submit to server side.  The only exception is if it's the Day dropdown I've left blank.  If I've instead left the Month dropdown blank the validator is not working.

Is what I want to do achievable?  It seems like overkill to put this validator on each of the 5 controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact that you have put this validator on the Day dropdown. To make it work, it should call $.validator.methods.required.call for the proper empty element, something like this:

```
if (value == "" || mv == "" || yv == "" || hv == "" || mnv == "") {
    if (value != "" || mv != "" || yv != "" || hv != "" || mnv != "") {
        if (value == "")
            $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
        if (mv == "")
            $.validator.methods.required.call(this, mv, controlmonth, parameters);
        if (yv == "")
            $.validator.methods.required.call(this, yv, controlyear, parameters);
        if (hv == "")
            $.validator.methods.required.call(this, hv, controlhour, parameters);
        if (mnv == "")
            $.validator.methods.required.call(this, mnv, controlminute, parameters);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code is still not perfect but it should give you an idea in which direction you should go.

Comment: Thanks that got me going.  I needed to reference controlmonth[0] and controlyear[0] etc. for some strange reason but I got it working.  Thanks.

Comment: Right, the reason is that the variables are jQuery objects, not DOM elements. The jQuery object holds the actual element under it's [0] indexer. I've forget about that in the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't unobtrusive validation, its highly obtrusive validation.

To use unobtrusive validation, decorate your model with attributes, eg:

```
    public class ValidationModel {
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
 
    [Required, StringLength(60)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 
    [Range(1, 130)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Use the MVC Helpers for HTML inputs and validation Messages:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)                                  
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)                                   
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Age)
```

Include the JQuery Validate Lirary and the unobtrusive validation library:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript">
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript">
```

Enable Unobtrusive validation  in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Inspect the elements in firebug to make sure the unobtrusive "data-val" attributes are appended e.g.:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Name must be a string with a maximum length of 5." data-val-length-max="5" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
```

And validation will just work, no javascript required, completely unobtrusive.

More info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

http://thepursuitofalife.com/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-javascript-validation-with-custom-validators/

Comment: I do believe that he understands the framework and this script is just an implementation of ValidationType (dtdt) for ModelClientValidationRule. This is just a very specific custom validator which has dependencies on other fields.

Comment: This sample would insist on FirstName and LastName to be both required.  If you applied the rule I want to your example I would want the FirstName AND LastName to be required OR the FirstName and LastName to both be empty.  Note: As for the rest of your example, I have created my own custom required field on my Day property in my model it works fine server side.